# how to check if folder name meets requirement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

users are supposed to drop folders in a directory

```
string sourcepath
```

how to check if all folders and files in the directory have correct format of "numbers space numbers space numbers space" such as "123 456 789" I would thing the pseudocode
would be something like this:

```
  DirectoryInfo parentFolderInfo = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath);

        foreach (DirectoryInfo folder in parentFolderInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            if (sourcepath == "correct name")
            {
                FileInfo[] filesInSource = folder.GetFiles();

                foreach (FileInfo file in filesInSource)
                {
                    if (file == "correct name")
                    {
                        //do something 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //return box "the folder name is wrong please try again
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //return box "the folder name is wrong please try again


            }
```

I think we have to use regular expression for this. thank you

Comment: What attitude? You theorized that you need to write a regular expression to validate these strings. However, we are not here to write your code for you. If you want a regular expression to be written, then it's up to you go to research what you need to do and write it. If you make a solid attempt and get stuck, then provide us a [MCVE] showing your work, sample input, actual output, and expected output and explain how it's not meeting your expectations.

Comment: You tried writing a regular expression? Then post the code as a [MCVE] in your question, along with the sample input, actual output, and expected output. If you do that, then your question will appear less like a "please write code for me" question and more like a "I have this code that's not working" question - which is exactly what the expectation is here on Stack Overflow for a question.

Comment: There is no output it is just if valid proceed, input example is mentioned above. regex no good progress to show, again logic and regex is the issue thus i posted pseudocode.

Comment: Valid or Not Valid is the output that you need to describe. Provide sample input, actual output, and expected output. Provide the regex that you attempted writing. Please don't make me repeat myself, as that's not a productive use of either of our time. I've given you the necessary information that you need to provide to avoid having your question closed - it's up to you to now provide that information in the question.

Comment: please read the question and comments thank you.

Comment: I have read them. You have consistently ignored giving the information I requested. You provided one example of valid input, but that hardly describes the full set of data you would expect it to match. You've not provided the regex you say you've created, nor an example of which inputs are succeeding and which are failing with that regex. Thus I'll leave my close vote in place. If you actually provide the information I've requested, feel free to ping me and I'll be glad to take a look and remove the close vote or vote to reopen if the question is in an answerable state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static string pattern = "((.*))([(.*)^\\s])([^\\(_.*)]+)([^\\s]+)";//change the regex ass needed
static Match result;
static string formatname = string.Empty;
DirectoryInfo parentFolderInfo = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath);
foreach (DirectoryInfo folder in foldersInSource.GetDirectories())//This loops through all folders from path
  {
    formatname = fileNameVaild.Name;//This gets the folder name 
    result = Regex.Match(fileNameVaild.Name, pattern);//This compares the two values
    if (result.Value == formatname)
       {
        continue;
       }
    else
       {
         return false;//if values != then return false.
       }
   }
```

I hope this gets someone started.